# Выделение лексем

Tags: c++, лексический-анализатор

Написать программу, использующую механизм управления при помощи таблиц (управление осуществляется данными!). 
Нужно выделить следующие типы лексем:

- Целое число со знаком
- Вещественное число со знаком
- Скобка

Ориентировочная схема работы главного цикла программы:

1. Ввод символа из файла
2. Переход автомата в новое состояние в зависимости от введенного символа и текущего состояния
3. Вывод символа в выходной файл, либо другое действие (в зависимости от задания)

Перевод автомата в новое состояние (п. 2) и выбор действия для выполнения (п. 3) могут быть реализованы несколькими способами. От способа реализации зависит максимальный балл за выполнение работы:
1.  Выбор действия и состояния с помощью ветвлений (if, switch) – 60%
2.  Выбор состояния с помощью таблицы (массива), а действия с помощью ветвления – 80%
3.  Выбор состояния и действия с помощью таблиц (для действий используются указатели на функции) – 100%

**Чуть позже узнал, что есть очень важные ограничения на реализацию:
программа может запоминать только текущее состояние и последний введенный символ. Не должны использоваться никакие дополнительные массивы или переменные для хранения введенных данных.**

После ограничений пришлось удалить весь код и набросать этот:
http://pastebin.ru/NlYjOVPg

Помогите разобраться, как мне полностью выделить лексему, например, несколько 123 - как целое со знаком, а не по отдельности, как 1 - целое со знаком, 2 - целое со знаком, 3 - целое со знаком.

[image: Таблица переходов]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@T2skler](/users/25847/t2skler), IMHO плодотворной идеей будет сделать для каждого состояния свою таблицу переходов. Причем, ячейка таблицы представляет собой два поля: действие (указатель на функцию) и новое состояние (указатель на соответствующую таблицу).

И для полноты картины введите еще один символ -- EOF.

Тогда достаточно следующих состояний:

- Start
- Sign
- Int
- Real

и действия:

- ERR
- ERR_AND_BRACKET
- BRACKET
- INT
- INT_AND_BRACKET
- REAL
- INT_AND_BRACKET
- NONE

Например, знак в состоянии Start вызывает NONE и переход к Sign, цифра в Sign вызывает NONE и переход в Int, знак в Int вызывает INT и переход в Sign, ... знак в Sign вызывает ERR и переход опять в Sign и т.п.

Теперь о загадочных XXX_AND_BRACKET.

Очевидно, что скобка в Start  вызывает BRACKET и переход в Start.

Скобка в Sign с одной стороны должна вызвать ошибку, а с другой -- это ведь просто лексема скобка. Поэтому вызовем ERR_AND_BRACKET, которая сначала вызовет ERR и затем BRACKET, а потом сразу перейдем в Start.

Похожим образом обработаем скобку в состояниях Int и Real. Только вместо ERR вызываем INT или REAL.

EOF в любом состоянии завершает программу (вероятно в состоянии Sign нужно вызвать ERR(?) или добавить действия XXX_AND_EOF, аналогичные XXX_AND_BRACKET)

Наверняка что-то упустил, но Вы уж сами додумайте... Попробуйте, думаю у Вас все получится.

Comment: Все условия продумали) Уже получилось написать код, только у меня просто добавлено новое состояние NEW_STATE. В него переходят, когда происходит было, например, число, а потом появилась скобка. Выводятся накопившиеся символы (к примеру 123) и сразу же повторно запрашивается состояние для текущего символа и обрабатывается далее.

Comment: @T2skler, код на 100%? 

Т.е. только с таблицами и указателями на функции?

Comment: Нет, я не совсем понял, как это нужно реализовывать

Comment: как называется состояние, когда мы находимся в середине лексемы (например, в середине числа)? Я не вижу, как можно, используя только Start, Sign, Int, Real состояния, распознать ввод, если хранить только текущее состояние (допустим, номер от 0 до 3 включительно) и последний введенный символ (один байт для простоты). Для сравнения, [конечный автомат из моего ответа](http://imgur.com/uKFLexy) использует 8 состояний.

Comment: В середине целого -- в состоянии Int, действительного -- Real, естественно.

Дело ведь в том, что требуется только распознавать лексемы, а не получить сами числа. Скажем, все входные символы можно сразу печатать, а при распознании лексемы (или ошибки) вставлять сообщение в выходной поток.

Только с балансировкой скобок при заданных условиях будут проблемы.

По крайней мере сейчас (без детальной проработки) мне это так видится. 

--

При случае (время, желание) черкану программульку.

Comment: Пока десятичная точка не прочитана (или экспонента), Real выглядит как Int. Или Ваш алгоритм предусматривает прыганье в середине числа (Int -> Real)? Или не понятно, какие состояния соответствуют "--" (ошибочный ввод).

Для сравнения можно посмотреть [какие таблицы ragel генерирует (см. Makefile чтобы получить C файл)](https://gist.github.com/zed/610ac3d438265c231570)

Comment: Именно так. Точка внутри Int -- переход в Real. Вообще в данном случае в Real можно попасть только из Int.

Кстати, я тут чуть подумал и понял, что если мы хотим считать `123.` (и т.п.) ошибкой, а не Real, то все-таки придется ввести еще одно состояние.

Answer (score 4):

Если кол-во состояний конечно и можно запоминать только номер текущего состояния и последний введённый символ, то узнать что мы прочитали 123, а не 213 нельзя. В противном случае кол-во состояний было бы пропорционально вводу или сам ввод (или позиции в нём) необходимо отдельно хранить.

Зная только состояние внутри конечного автомата и текущий символ, можно определить было ли прочитано целое, действительное числа или скобка.

Например, [ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) позволяет создать конечный автомат из регулярного выражения:

```
%%{
    machine number_fsm;

    integer = ('+' | '-')? digit+;
    float = ('+' | '-')? (digit+ ('.' digit*)? | '.' digit+)
            (('e' | 'E') ('+' | '-')? digit+)?;
    paren = '(' | ')';
    token = integer | float | paren;

    main := token**;

}%%
```

[image: картинка c конечным автоматом]
. Чтобы получить эту картинку, необходимо сохранить вышеприведённый код в `number_fsm.rl` файл и выполнить команды:

```
$ ragel -F1 -p -V -o number_fsm.dot number_fsm.rl
$ dot -Tpng -o number_fsm.png number_fsm.dot
$ display number_fsm.png
```

ragel также умеет генерировать таблицы перехода для состояний и исполнять действия в любом месте на выбранном языке (например, С, Go).

Comment: @jfs: Почему же невозможно? Пусть количество состояний будет равно `MAXINT` :-) Для целых чисел хватит, для действительных придётся подкинуть ещё.

---
Чтобы упростить программирование, можно под номер состояния выделить `double`.

Comment: Поскольку требуется только распознавать целые, действительные числа и скобки, *но не требуется выводить конкретное число* (для этого потребовалась бы дополнительная переменная для сосояний INT и REAL), то число состояний резко уменьшается и задача, безусловно, решается без lex/flex/ragel и т.п.  
(просто сейчас лень расписывать таблицу переходов).

Comment: @VladD: невозможно. Кол-во натуральных чисел бесконечно. Если ограничить ввод, то все алгоритмы `O(1)`, что не очень интересно или полезно.

@avp: верно (в этом смысл 2-го параграфа в ответе). Но таблицы всё-таки лучше компьютерам оставить составлять (легче изменять регулярные выражения чем таблицы переходов, меньше ошибок).

Comment: @jfs, Вы же наверняка понимаете, что задача у @T2skler, состоит не в создании рабочего лексера, а в написании учебной машины состояний (просто входные данные для нее ассоциируются с языками программирования). 

Если продолжить аналогии, то дана задача -- "написать вычисления по формуле ... **на ассемблере**", а ему все дружно в ответ -- **не дури, пиши на ...** (у кого какой язык любимый).

Конечно, если речь идет о проекте (который предположительно еще и будет развиваться), включающим какой-либо язык (или язык не простой), то надо потратить пару неделек и освоить lex/yacc (или аналоги).

Comment: @jfs: Количество «натуральных» чисел `MAXINT + 1`, с точки зрения языка.

Если брать «правильные» натуральные числа, бесконечное множество, то имея конечную память очевидно невозможно распарсить строку в такое число. (Если, конечно, нам не нужно само число, то DFA на `[+|-] \d+` совсем уж тривиален.)

Comment: @avp: нет. Я прекрасно понимаю задание -- оно идиотское. Это всё равно что заставлять людей в столбик числа с сотнями цифрами вычислять -- я могу понять две-три цифры для тренировки, чтобы знать как это делается. Правильный ответ это использовать компьютер, чтобы сгенерировать код (и если учитель идиот, то можно не упоминать средства, которыми таблицы были получены).

@VladD: автомат, который приведён в ответе будет работать для любого числа (пока память в компьютере не закончится), даже если на С реализован: представь многогигабайтный файл, который содержит целое число.

Comment: @jfs: Этот автомат, судя из его описания, лишь убеждается в том, что на вход подано число, но не вычисляет _само число_.

Comment: @VladD: если хочется вывести *само число*, то можно легко запомнить *позиции*, где число начинается во вводе и где оно заканчивается (достоинство ragel по сравнению с lex, что действие можно в любое место добавить, в частности: при распознавании начала или конца числа). Вот [пример сканера](https://gist.github.com/zed/610ac3d438265c231570), который хранит начало/конец числа в ts/te указателях.

Comment: @jfs: Не-не-не, это грязный трюк. Таким образом вы выводите «сырой» текст, который парсится, а не разобранный осмысленный объект. Представьте себе, что число записано в троичной системе, парсер от этого почти не поменяется, а вот вывести его (в нормальной, десятичной) вы не сможете.

Comment: @VladD: можно на ходу преобазовать из троичной в десятичную (или в какую захочется) -- я (почти) уверен, что это можно сделать, используя О(1) памятью за один проход (одновременно со чтением). Но эта задача уже совсем далека, от простого выделения лексем в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs: Я не говорю про это конкретное задание. Я о том, что результатом лексического анализа должен быть _сам объект_, а не строка, его представляющая. И именно это есть смысл: не выделение _типов_ лексем, а пар (тип лексемы, значение лексемы правильного типа).

В данном случае — не строка, представляющая натуральное число, а само число.

Comment: @VladD: в вопросе **жирным** выделено ограничение на задачу, которое не позволяет само число отдельно запоминать (так как это требует в общем случае памяти пропорциональной самому вводу `O(n)`). Результат лексического анализа как правило является последовательность лексем. Ничто не мешает лексемам указывать на ввод, если это подходит для задачи ([`ts`, `te` указатели в коде](https://gist.github.com/zed/610ac3d438265c231570) обозначают "Token Start", "Token End").

Answer (score 2):

Я года три назад писал небольшой скриптовой язык и интересовался вопросом. Как выше написал [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), не стоит изобретать велосипед. Проще всего воспользоваться [Flex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_%28%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%29). Ему задаешь определенные правила, а на выходе он генерирует C'шный код, который уже легко встраиваешь под задачу.

Это сэкономит тебе кучу времени, а в итоге получешь отличный код.

P.S. Если не ошибаюсь он умеет и в C++.

Answer (score 1):

Не стройте велосипед, воспользуйтесь `lex`/`flex`.